# method for tracking/timestamping proxy API calls javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to either use a pre-existing method or create a method for a nodeJS proxy balancer. I would like to have the option for the user to have a timeout after X number of calls are reached in Y timeframe. For example, after 100 calls in 2 minutes have a 3 minute timeout. I'm trying to add it to this repo here which I forked https://github.com/KevinDanikowski/proxy-balancer . Any recommendations?

I thought about these options:

1. add some value to the proxy array objects
2. Use some 3rd party package (not sure which one would do this) to track it
3. create an array of proxy calls and time stamps and do filtering. This is my current solution I'm thinking, would be nice if a 3rd party did this.

(Ideally it would be performant)

Comment: are you searming like a rate-limiter? like this one: https://github.com/nfriedly/express-rate-limit

Comment: @Sysix boom that's exactly what I wanted, just gotta find a way to extract the logic, it looks like that is purely middleware

Comment: which framework are you using to handle request's and response's?

Comment: @Sysix got was my plan, currently it's set up to handle what ever handler you pass it